# Alternative to FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview, fragmentstatepageradapter

I want to find a replacement to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter + PagerFragment as we all know the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is still broken up to this day when we somehow reorder/add fragments to the adapter. There have been a bunch of attempts on github and by myself to make something that mimics the functionality of the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, except all of them seem to have extremely complicated logic with bugs that seem impossible to debug, e.g. https://gist.github.com/ypresto/8c13cb88a0973d071a64.

Does anyone know any alternative to reordering fragments aside from taking the FragmentStatePagerAdapter source code and making your own.

Comment: Use a `RecyclerView` -- see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerViewPager/DynSnap).

Comment: @CommonsWare Whenever you scroll the list it'll need to be re-created and run its various setup methods which will be quite expensive? Since I have multiple types of fragments..

Comment: Um, well, `RecyclerView` recycles views. It's kinda in the name. :-) So, performance should be comparable to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, from that standpoint. However, `RecyclerView` uses views, not fragments.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yea :P So your example app recycles fragments instead of views?

Comment: No, it recycles views, because it uses `RecyclerView`. However, with snap helpers, you can have a `RecyclerView` that visually behaves like a `ViewPager`, and `RecyclerView` is very robust with respect to changing the contents of what should be rendered.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have any examples about choosing `RecyclerView` to replace `FSPA`? Thank you. :)

Comment: @Alston: See [this directory of sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/RecyclerViewPager), covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android).